# completing the square in multivariate gaussian

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a question while I studying PRML - Gaussian Distribution.
When completing the square in multivariate Gaussian,
[image]

in above equation, I'm wondering why
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $\mu$ are length $p$ vectors and $\Sigma$ is a $p \times p$ matrix (thus $\Sigma^{-1}$ is $p \times p$), you will notice that the resulting product is a scalar in both cases (I.e. dimension $1 \times 1$.)

Now the other piece of information you need is that the transpose of a scalar is just the scalar you stated with, thus the two quantities must be equal

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: It's also important that $\Sigma^{-1}$ is symmetric; otherwise the two quantities wouldn't be the transpose of each other.

Comment: yes you're right, thank you!

Comment: @user20160 yes good point (+1). Although I'd taken that as given since $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix

Comment: then I have additional question. if B is symmetric matrix, then ABC = CBA is this equation always right? if right, why?